# Full Jquery support in Karma E2E testing in AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

How do I access the full JQuery library within my Karma E2E tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a config file?  Just [include it like any other](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/files.html):

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'angular.js',
  'jquery.js',
  // etc...
];
```

Comment: Ok I will try it tomorrow. But will it automatically replace the built in library just like it does in the regular code?